# Connected components via recursive traversal missing one node [python]

Tags: python, graph-theory, graph-traversal, connected-components

Trying to do a very quick connected components algorithm of a graph by taking each vertex, traversing it, then skipping to the next vertex that hasn't already been assigned to a component.

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCom6.png)

This is the graph. The output I currently get is: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]

Which shows mostly correct output except that neither v1 or v4 correctly call v5 to assign it a group, so it's recognized as it's own group. Not sure why this is the case.

```
adjacency_matrix = [[0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]]

def Connected_Component(graph):
     # Number of vertices = Number of rows in matrix
     vertices = graph.__len__()
     # Array of zeroes to hold vertex component values
    components = [0] * vertices
    # Component groups start at 1, so 0 means unassigned
    current_component = 1

# Search all vertices connected
def traverse(vertex):
    # For each edge of this vertex
    for edge in range(0,vertex.__len__()):
        if vertex[edge] == 1:
            # Base case: If the vertex corresponding to the edge has already been visited & assigned a component
            if components[edge] > 0:
                print "Base case on " + str(edge) + " current component " + str(current_component)
                return
            # Otherwise, recursively search each connected vertex
            else:
                components[edge] = current_component
                print "recursively traversing " + str(edge)+ " current component " + str(current_component)
                traverse(graph[edge])

for vertex in range(0,vertices):
    # If the component of the current vertex has already been assigned, skip this iteration
    if components[vertex] > 0:
        print "skipping " + str(vertex)
        continue
    else:
        # Traverse this vertex
        print "traversing " + str(vertex)+ " current component " + str(current_component)
        traverse(graph[vertex])
        current_component += 1

return components
```

print Connected_Component(adjacency_matrix)

Comment: It looks like you are just throwing recursive calls at a dartboard and hoping they stick. You should follow a strategy which will visit all paths once. Look up "depth first search" and "breadth first search". Debugging will show the actual error (when looking at vertex 1's edges, it sees that it is connected to vertex 2, which has already been assigned, so it decides not to evaluate any more of vertex 1's edges, so it will never see ... for example the edge from vertex 1 to vertex 5.)

Comment: Also, a vertex can't have a 0 in the correct answer. If vertex 5 had actually been disconnected, it should still be its own connected component (the only 2 in the output).